# Ruby -- When I call a method on an array, do I need to specify the argument inside the method to be the name of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

When I call a method on an array, do I need to specify the argument inside the method to be the name of an array?

For example, version 1 seems much natural for me but gives me an error. I thought I do not have a restriction when it comes to setting an argument in a method which only stays within the body of the method.

## version 1

```
duplicated = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]

def unique_method(item)
    unique = []

    duplicated.each do |item|
        if ! unique.include?(item) #argument here, problem occurs
            unique << item
        end
    end
    return unique
end

puts unique_method(duplicated)
```

## version 2

```
duplicated = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]

def unique_method(duplicated) #argument here, this code runs.

unique = []

duplicated.each do |item|
    if ! unique.include?(item)
        unique << item
    end
end

return unique
end

puts unique_method(duplicated)
```

Answer (score 3):

## 1st version

```
duplicated = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]

def unique_method(item)
    unique = []

    # ↓ Problem occurs here. duplicated isn't defined.
    duplicated.each do |item|
        if ! unique.include?(item)
            unique << item
        end
    end
    return unique
end

puts unique_method(duplicated)
#=> NameError!
```

Inside your method, `duplicated` isn't defined. That's the error you get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `duplicated' for main:Object
from (pry):5:in `unique_method'
```

Also, it's generally not a good idea to use the same name for two different variables ("shadowing") :

- `item` is an array inside your method
- `item` is an element of this array inside the each loop.

## 2nd version

It works fine.
If using a parameter disturbs you, you could put this method in `Array` class. Your array is now `self` :

```
class Array
  def unique_method
    unique = []
    self.each do |item|
      unique << item unless unique.include?(item)
    end
    unique
  end
end

p duplicated.unique_method
#=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
```

You don't have to use `return` in the last line of your method.

You could also use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and save a few lines :

```
class Array
  def unique
    each_with_object([]) do |item, unique|
      unique << item unless unique.include?(item)
    end
  end
end
```

Methods usually don't have "method" in their names. `Array#unique` would be fine.

Finally, you could also use the already defined [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq). ;)

Comment: Thank you!!! I get it now. In the version 1 method, the argument should be named "duplicated" since the method does not contain an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. First you are defining the variable `item` twice inside your method. First time here

```
def unique_method(item)
```

second time here

```
duplicated.each do |item|
```

The second definition will overshadow the first.

The second issue is that you are passing `duplicated` into your method (where you have it called "item") but are never using it because it's overshadowed (the first problem I mentioned).

Here is your first version fixed:

```
duplicated = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]

def unique_method(items)
    unique = []

    items.each do |item|
        if ! unique.include?(item) #argument here, problem occurs
            unique << item
        end
    end
    return unique
end

puts unique_method(duplicated)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I now see the importance of using different variables. I had mistaken that  "item" variables are connected. But it was the variable "duplicated" that was an argument for the method.